# Dataframe to append new column with values from other dataframe when if statement between two dataframes match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2

df1:

```
                       date   
0       2002-06-02 00:00:00       
1       2002-06-02 06:00:00           
2       2002-06-02 12:00:00  
3       2002-06-02 18:00:00           
4       2002-06-03 00:00:00   
5       2002-06-03 06:00:00           
6       2002-06-03 12:00:00
```

df2:

```
                       date  total  
0       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN       
1       2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000       
2       2002-06-04 00:00:00  NaN
```

Desired output:

```
    date  total  
0       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN       
1       2002-06-02 06:00:00  NaN       
2       2002-06-02 12:00:00  NaN   
3       2002-06-02 18:00:00  NaN 
4       2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000         
5       2002-06-03 06:00:00  NaN 
6       2002-06-03 12:00:00  NaN
```

Here is the code that I have attempted:

```
df1['total'] = df1['date'].map(df2.set_index('date')['total'])
```

However, what I get as an output is this....

```
                       date  total  
0       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN       
1       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN       
2       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN   
3       2002-06-02 00:00:00  NaN 
4       2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000         
5       2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000 
6       2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000
```

I am new to python and hope someone can help me resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Why not use LEFT JOIN on df1.date = df2.date ? ,sry for not giving you the exact code as I am from Spark-Scala background. But concept is the same. 
Try JOINING both Dataframes

Comment: Hi Abhishek, the df1['date'] and df['date'] don't match in length; df1['date'] increases by increments of 6 hours and df2['date'] increases by increments of 24 hours

Comment: 4       2002-06-03 00:00:00   vs  1    2002-06-03 00:00:00  120000     

Here I can see both column has same exact content.

Comment: where matches like 4 2002-06-03 00:00:00 vs 1 2002-06-03 00:00:00 occur, the total from df2 should appear alongside as shown in 'Desired Ouput'

Comment: the date column's content matches exactly for both data-frames.
I think this is what you want.

Comment: In need the date and time

Comment: I have just tried  the following code but it produces issues with the time also, changes all times to 00:00:00       df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index('date'), on = 'date')
print(df3)

Comment: val df3 = df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), Seq("date"), "left").na.fill("NaN", Seq("total")).drop("id")
I tried this.It works ,though this code is in scala

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and advice, i found that 'join' actually once I changed the 'date' format

Comment: Great to hear that ! happy coding :)